# AFNetworking Requests fails with -999 error code

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

Since i updated the AFNetworking from 3.0.4 to 3.1.0 i am getting errr -999 when downloading a file. I am making a post request to the server with some data, and if the data is valid a file will be download, otherwise and error JSON will be return.

here is the code:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setSecurityPolicy:policy];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:DEFAULT_TIMEOUT];
[manager POST:[[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:ACTION_UPDATE_DB] stringByAppendingString:API_KEY]
   parameters:defaultData
     progress:nil
      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id responseObject) {

      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

      }];
```

I have tried changing to this, but with the same result.

```
AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
[policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are few issues that your problem mentioned, please check them out;

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2895

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2312

Comment: I have checked that, but those are all old issues. and this was cause by the last update.